# ADFS 3.0 with SAML Logout URL Does Not Work

Tags: java, saml-2.0, adfs, opensaml, adfs3.0

We have configured our application as relying party in ADFS. We are able to login using ADFS + SAML, however logout is not working as expected.

Post logout, we want to redirect the user to the home page of our application..

Here are the details of our attempts:
Under ADFS relying properties, **SAML Logout endpoint -> Binding = POST**

1. Trusted URL = "https://XXX.XX/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0"
   Response URL = "application home page URL"

Result = Remains on ADFS logout page only.

2. Trusted URL = "application home page URL"
   Response URL = blank

Result = Works for the first time logout. SAMLSession cookie gets removed from the browser. Redirection to application home page is successful.
**However, for subsequent logout in the same browser session, it remain on the ADFS logout page. SAMLSession cookie is also retained in the browser.**